# Gensim word2vec score function when out-of-vocabulary

Tags: gensim

Word2Vec cannot handle out-of-vocabulary words (returns an error). However, when I try the score function https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.score
with sentences including OOV words, surprisingly, I do not get an error. Why is this the case?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `score()` function is a training-like function, and like `train()` itself, simply ignores unknown words as if they weren't there. (Pondering whether this is the right decision or not for the goals of such 'scoring' is the subject of a nearby [source-code-comment](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/7d7bb84598e2e02e839b38c6b662d4357cbdce0a/gensim/models/word2vec_inner.pyx#L741).)

Note that these `score()` functions are a non-standard extension of `Word2Vec` contributed a while ago as part of the research paper mentioned in the related docs. Whether they work for any purpose, or still work for as originally intended in the latest versions of Gensim, isn't clear or certain. They might not be maintained in the future (and even now don't work in for usual default negative-sampling `Word2Vec` models).

So, you may not want to rely on them, and should study their raw source for info on their functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarifications. The reason why I am currently using score is to evaluate my trained model on a separate corpus (validation set). Specifically, I am using it as a metric to compare different trained models (trained on different corpus sizes) on the same validation set. Is there any other metric that you would suggest to use instead?

Comment: What do you expect this metric, applied to non-training data, to tell you? (Are you using it as a sort of classfier, as in the the research paper linked from the docs for thoe `score()` function, or for some other purpose?) What do you think a high or low `score` value is telling you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My ultimate goal is to decide what corpus size I should (is enough to) use for training w2v. To this end, I thought to train different models, gradually increasing the training set size, and monitor a validation loss/metric on a separate corpus. Based on when this loss/metric stabilises, I would decide the training set size needed.
I could as well use the loss function for this, however, I could not find a related gensim function.
I would highly appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: I don't know a grounded reason why the `score()` would be good for that purpose. Neither `score` nor other related measures of loss are reliable indicators of a `Word2Vec` model's absolute fitness for a particular purpose, nor are they indicators of a training set's sufficiency. Notably, loss can go almost arbitrarily smaller by expanding the model without expanding the training data - but as your loss drops, the model can become so overfit to the idiosyncratic training data that it loses usefulness-via-generalization elsewhere. You should prefer evaluations specific to your goals instead.

Comment: Thank you. Sure, training loss can go arbitrary smaller, however validation loss would increase in that case. We could use early stopping for each model and then compare the resulting validation losses.

Comment: So was the hope to use the `score` return-value as an early-stopping guide? (I'm still not clear where this `score` value could provide added value - especially given its extra limitations, like only working in the non-default `hs=1` mode.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I would like to use some value (either loss or score) both for (a) early stopping each model (trained with different corpus sizes) (b) given the validation loss/score of each model (after early stopping), decide on the size of the training corpus to eventually use (based on when the loss/score value stabilizes, while increasing the training corpus size of the models).

Is there a gensim function that I could use to get the (validation) loss, so as I avoid using the score?

Comment: I understand the desire for early-stopping; unfortunately Gensim has no direct support for the that. The option (only working in `Word2Vec`, not its sibling classes) for `compute_loss=True` at model-creation will let you then use `get_latest_training_loss()` to get a running tally of all loss so far – but it needs adjustment to be a per-epoch total or running-average, and may require other workarounds for precision bugs, & calling `train()` multiple times (or using callbacks) are both a bit clunky & error-prone for the purpose of early-stopping.

Comment: There's an open project issues discussing some of the ways loss-tallying should be fixed – https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2617 (which includes links to related bugs) – but no one has stepped up to address that need well. I don't quite understand your intended use of one of these measures to "descied on the size of the training corpus" - it seems a project-specific quality score should drive that moreso than a training-loss measure, but maybe I'm missing something. Is this a training-corpus-sizing technique that's documented/recommended in some writeup?